# Trying to Install Sklearn on Python 3.8 Gives an Error

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm trying to install sklearn (scikit-learn) on Python 3.8 on Windows 10 using the following:

```
pip install sklearn
```

I've also used:

```
pip3 install sklearn

pip install scikit-learn 

pip install -U scikit-learn
```

As well as:

```
pip install --only-binary :all: sklearn
```

I've also tried upgrading pip/setuptools.

There is a long block of errors; among them, the portion which seems to be relevant mentions Fortran:

> ```
>   customize GnuFCompiler
>   Could not locate executable g77
>   Could not locate executable f77
>   customize IntelVisualFCompiler
>   Could not locate executable ifort
>   Could not locate executable ifl
>   customize AbsoftFCompiler
>   Could not locate executable f90
>   customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
>   Could not locate executable DF
>   customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
>   Could not locate executable efl
>   customize Gnu95FCompiler
>   Could not locate executable gfortran
>   Could not locate executable f95
>   customize G95FCompiler
>   Could not locate executable g95
>   customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
>   customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
>   Could not locate executable efort
>   Could not locate executable efc
>   customize PGroupFlangCompiler
>   Could not locate executable flang
>   don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
>     NOT AVAILABLE
> ```

Another part of the error:

> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils;

I'm just wondering if this is because of the newness of 3.8? Is there a workaround anyone is aware of?

It seems to revolve around NumPy. I've uninstalled that package and reinstalled it.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -U scikit-learn`? This is what they suggest on their website.

Comment: I have and should have added that - I've also tried again just now to be sure. Will add to question. It did result in the same error message. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please try `pip install --upgrade pip` then try installing again?

Comment: This also didn't work, although my pip is now upgraded. I also ran the command `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, as I ran into an error afterward and came across that as a proposed solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12016#issuecomment-544953139) saying the following (16 days ago):

> Python 3.8 is not officially supported by NumPy yet. We strongly suggest you stick with python 3.7 for now, until you see a 3.8 designation in the "Programming Language" section of the PyPI numpy page (probably several weeks) or until an Anaconda release with Python 3.8 is available (probably several months)

So it looks like it might be the underlying dependencies just not working with 3.8 yet. I actually had a similar issue with another package last week. You will probably have luck if you get a [3.7.5 install](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-375/). Make sure you get the right platform (x86 for 32-bit, x64 for 64 bit) and make sure you check the box to add it to your path.

I'm guessing you're on Windows yes? If so then after the install open a powershell and enter `gcm python` and `gcm pip` to make sure they are being pulled from the 3.7 install. If not, you'll have to edit PATH in the system environment variables and move the new Python37 directory before Python38 in your PATH.

Hope that solves the issue!

Comment: Looks like that's the route I'll go. Was excited for the walrus operator, but alas - thanks! Will definitely fuss about in the environment variables and get that part working.

Answer (score 5):

Try to run `pip install --pre -f https://sklearn-nightly.scdn8.secure.raxcdn.com scikit-learn`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in command prompt:

```
py -m pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an explanation on the given command? Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65451897/edit) to add more details.